# Matlab - Command Window and variable editor difference

Tags: matlab

This is confusing me.. Ok, so I have the same dataset and I'm viewing them in the output window as well as the variable editor and they are completely different. Here is the screenshot:
 [image]

Notice how the 9th element is "0" whereas on the variable editor it is "-0.0078"

The code:

```
function f = display()
rawdata = wavread('FILENAME', 'double');
f = rawdata;
end
```

Any ideas? I don't know which is right and which is wrong.

Comment: question, are you viewing FILENAME and displaying rawdata?

Comment: wavread samples a dataset. easily probable that this is the source of the differences

Comment: @AK4749 So which dataset is correct? I.e. I'm trying to do the project in C++ and matching it against what I get in C++.. The output in the variable editor is the exact same as I have in C++ however, it is different to the one in the cmd window. Thanks :)

Comment: are you sure this isn't a scrolling issue? Meaning that the top value in the command window ISN'T index 1?

Comment: @slayton Actually, it could be.. The final output variables are EXACTLY the same. Werid

Comment: @Phorce, that's the thing, they are different datasets. if indeed you are viewing FILENAME in the variable editor and displaying rawdata, what's happening is that wavread is SAMPLING your dataset. It is now a different dataset. Does that make sense? It probably should if you're doing this project

Comment: I think @slayton is right. I would check under File>Preferences>Command Window to see how many lines are in the scroll buffer. Mine is set to 5,000, so this variable (length 57884) would definitely fill past that.

Comment: @AK4749 So how do I get the raw data sample, without the sampling? My results in C++ are kinda the same as I get in MATLAB.. Is there an error somewhere? arghh!

Comment: oh man i need to get out from behind the company firewall, I didn't even notice there was a screenshot haha let me check it on my phone

Comment: ok 1) if it is a scrolling issue, just scroll up on both and make sure it is a scrolling issue. if it's not, how is your dataset organized in the file? If it's rectangular, just use the `load` command

Answer (score 1):

The default scroll buffer in the command window is 5000 lines. Consequently, if you're looking at variables with more than 5000 rows (~60k in your case), you'll only see the last 4999 or so entries.

Consequently, you'll either need to increase the scroll buffer, output the transpose of your vector, or use the variable editor (which is right).